# Is there a way to link html sections to an html file?

Tags: html

Every time I make an edit in the navigation bar, I have to copy and paste this change into each .html page.
Is there a way to link one html file, I'd call navigation.html, into all the other files the same way css is performed?
That way I make one change to the navigation, and it updates all the links?

Does something like `<a href="navigation.html ref="(html or whatever) type="html?"` exist?

Comment: Currently such functionality only exists server-side. [SSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) springs to mind.

Comment: you can write a javascript file and write html code in navigation like innerHtml